# How can I get jQuery printElement to print a div with css class?

Tags: jquery, css, printing

I am trying to print a div with the printElement plugin. I it printing and everything is fine exept that it does not print css class at all. I have tried a lot of things like adding a class to the print element or adding css code.

Here is what i have for a code not

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#print").click(function() {
    $("#fullReport").printElement(
    { 
    styleToAdd:'padding:10px; margin:10px; color:red; width:100%;'
    }
    );
});
</script>
```

This should at least make the color of the div red when i click on the print div. The print preview does not change the color or the width!

can some one please help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Printing page colors is a setting in the browser and I don't think there is a way to force the browser to print what would be considered a background color.

You'd need to do an alternative, like use background images to fill DIV's, or use a COM service on your server to take a "snapshot" of your page to convert to JPG or something.

I've ran into this problem using jQuery based bar-graph software. What I ended up doing is running a COM service that I could call on the server that converts a page into a JPG.

If I had to do it again, I'd probably just use repeating background images instead of colors.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should also add
  printBodyOptions:
            {
                    styleToAdd:'padding:10px; margin:10px; color:red; width:100%;'
                } and Make sure you print with a colour printer